# Issues after suspend on ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I just installed ubuntu 20 yesterday on my new laptop and notice that when the computer wakes up from suspend it sometimes has one of the following issues:

- Screen does not turn on
- Screen turns on but I cannot login. Mouse has a pointer cursor but when I click it does not bring up the login prompt. Keyboard also does not bring up the login prompt.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if there is any other info I should include and I can edit.

Thanks